# Defining nested dependencies between your local web app and a CDN

Tags: javascript, asp.net, requirejs, cdn, amd

I am trying to define a nested dependency from a CDN module.

**I GET THE FOLLOWING ERROR: config**

Line: 1765
Error: ./modules/MyConcreteWidget/templates.htm HTTP status: 404

It seems as though the CDN **"text!./pathing"** thinks it is in the LOCAL web application.
All the files referenced do indeed exist in the CDN and can be brought-up through the browsers address bar.

Do I have to wrap the call to "MyWidget" in a require (itself)?

**LOCAL REQUIRE CONFIG LOOKS LIKE:**

```
require.config({
    paths:
    {
        , jquery: '/scripts/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min'
        , jsRender: '/scripts/jQuery/jsrender-1.0pre'
        , text: '/scripts/RequireJS/2.1.4/text-2.0.5'
        , domReady: '/scripts/RequireJS/2.1.4/domReady-2.0.1'
        , 'myConcreteWidget': '/Modules/MyConcreteWidget/control' 
        , 'myWidet': 'http://server1/Modules/MyWidget/control'
    },
shim:
    {
        'jsRender': { deps: ['jquery'] }
    }
});
```

**LOCAL REQUIRE LOOKS LIKE:**

```
require(['myConcreteWidget', 'domReady'],

    function (myConcreteWidget, domReady) {

        domReady(function () {

                // Use the concrete widget here...
        });
    });
```

**LOCAL DEFINE LOOKS LIKE: myConcreteWidget**
This define would use the CDN "Widget" as a dependency.

```
define(
    [
        'myWidget'
    ],
    function (myWidget) {

        var concrete = new myWidget.MyWidget();

        // Configure the concrete here...

        // Return concrete widget here
        return concrete;
    });
```

**CDN DEFINE LOOKS LIKE: myWidget**

```
define(
    [
      'jquery'
    , 'jsRender'
    , 'text!./templates.htm'
    ],
    function ($, jsRender, templates) {

        $('body').append(templates);

        function MyWidget(){
            this.widgetId = 0;
            this.name = 'Something Awesome';
        };

        return { MyWidget: MyWidget};
    });
```

**UPDATE:**
The templates file is nothing but SCRIPT tags (for the templates).

Answer (score 1):

Relative module IDs are resolved relative to a reference ID, not a path. So in this case, since 'myWidget' asks for './templates', it gets resolved to just 'templates' which is at the top of the module ID namespace, and so looked up under baseUrl, unless there is other config, like paths config in play. So you could probably put in a paths entry for 'template' to get the resolution you want.

Also note that there are cross domain restrictions with the text plugin: https://github.com/requirejs/text